# How to compare string like start with in command Line

Tags: cmd

I Have this this folders:

- 912
- 913
- 920
- 1012

And i need create and condition that compare those value but only a part of the string

for example if i have this variable  `directory` and I can compare: something  like this

```
IF (directory LIKE "91%")
   --------
```

But i dont know how to make this with Windows CommandLine.. Thanks

Comment: Describe actual examples of what you need to do.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Sounds like the job for a script?  Batch may be able to do what you're asking, but I'm not sure 100% what that is yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I'll try to guess, what you want to do:

You want to check if the value of a variable "directory" starts with a known string ("91")?

```
if "%directory:~0,2%"=="91"
```

`%var:~0,2%` takes two (`2`) chars from start (position `0`)